# Javascript Module Pattern Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, module

I've been following [this](http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/) tutoral, and when referencing Module as an argument in ModuleTwo, everything works fine **until I comment out Module**.

My understanding is that the double pipes || and empty object {} will create an empty object in place of Module if it's undefined, but instead I'm getting an error in the console.

```
var Module = (function () {

  var privateMethod = function () {
    // private
  };

  var someMethod = function () {
    // public
  };

  var anotherMethod = function () {
    // public
  };

  return {
    someMethod: someMethod,
    anotherMethod: anotherMethod
  };

})();

var ModuleTwo = (function (Module) {

    Module.extension = function () {
        // another method!
    };

    return Module;

})(Module || {});
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting in the console?

Comment: When you say you _"comment out Module"_, do you mean the variable declaration (i.e. ` var Module = ...`) or are you commenting out the `(Module || {} )` line?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there’s an error in the tutorial. One way to make things work was suggested by rplantiko, but it might be easier to just write `window.Module || {}` instead of `Module || {}`.

How things work here:

- Accessing a non-existent property of any object yields `undefined`. However, referencing a variable that hasn’t been declared yields `ReferenceError` (so your understanding was a little bit off there).
- Browser puts all global variables as properties onto global `window` object. `Module` in the tutorial is a global variable, because it’s declared outside all functions, so you can access it via `window.Module`, which will not cause `ReferenceError` if undefined (per previous point).

It might be a good practice to explicitly assign to `window` any global variable you define (e.g., do `window.Module = (function () { …` if you intend to make `Module` global), but that’s arguable and out of scope of this discussion.

Comment: sure, glad if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply the function defining your 2nd module to `(Module || {})`, the symbol `Module` cannot be resolved if the `Module` hasn't been declared earlier, which always gives a JavaScript error. If you want the 2nd Module to be defined even in the absence of the first Module, try the following:

```
var ModuleTwo = (function(Module) {
   ...
   })(typeof Module == 'object' ? Module : {} );
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the purpose of adding the || {} then?

Comment: As you expected, you can use the idiom `a = b || c` for the intention "assign b to a, but only if b doesn't evaluate to `false` (or `null` or `""` or `0` or...). If it does evaluate to `false`, the logical or is forced to evaluate c, and then c will be the result of the evaluation of the right-hand side. If b was not false, b will be the result of the rhs. But in your case, you can't use this idiom, because for an evaluation of an expression, all symbols must be known (except as argument of the `typeof` operator, hence my proposal above).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I really appreciate all the help.